# vs code unable to follow relative gcc build error links

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I've recently updated to ubuntu 20.04 with gcc 9.3.  I can no longer follow build errors from gcc in vs code since the error paths have been updated to be relative to the build directory instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is due to cmake / cmake-tools now using ninja as the generator which uses relative paths to the build directory.  To fix this in vs-code go to file -> settings -> CMake Tools Configuration -> Cmake: Generator.  Then enter "Unix Makefiles" as the generator.

Comment: This is a non-solution given the performance differences between Ninja and Make. If you haven't already, open an issue with VSCode.